# Cronjob to push MongoDB Backup via git

Tags: debian, cron

**Task:**
Create a Cronjob that executes a bash script once every night. The bash script should do a mongoDB Backup and push it to a Git Repo.

So I created a `cronjob` as the root user via the `crontab -e` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/root
HOME=/root

0 2 * * * /path/script.sh > /path/script.log
```

This is the script that should be executed:

```
BAK="/path"
#MONGO="/usr/bin/mongo"
#MONGODUMP="/usr/bin/mongodump"
#GIT="/usr/bin/git"

echo "starting backup"
echo $BAK
/usr/bin/mongodump --username=myusername --password=mypassword --db=mydatabase --out=$BAK$
echo "backup created"
/usr/bin/git add .
/usr/bin/git commit -m "backup from `date +'%Y_%m_%d'`"
echo "committed"
/usr/bin/git push -u origin master
echo "pushed backup. done"
```

**Outcome:**
Backups are being created but not pushed to the repository. Executing the script manually pushes the backups as desired. The Log only includes all the echo's from the script.

Comment: I don't think it is related to your issue, but your cronjob `* 2 * * *` is set to run “At every minute of 2nd hour.” If you want to run it “At 02:00 every day.” you should set it like `0 2 * * *`

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the right directory when issuing the `git` commands? In other words, when the `git add .` command is executed, does it know of any repository?

Try to `cd` into the `BAK` directory from your script using:

```
cd "$BAK"
```

Besides that, try to catch error output by appending `2>&1` to the cronjob line.

Another thing that I notice is the use of `$BAK$` at the `--out=` parameter. Seems a bit like `%VAR%` on Windows to me... Are you sure you want to output to `$BAK$` or do you mean `$BAK`?

Finally, are you sure you want to run this script every minute between 2.00am and 3.00am?